# iPad user interface programming tutorial for iPhone programmers?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, user-interface, interface-builder

I've been programming for the iPhone for quite a while now, but I still haven't made any iPad apps. 
(Well, a couple, but with childishly simple user interactions. Think tappable pictures.)

So, I'm familiar with XCode, IB, MVC, all that stuff. Despite that, I don't have a clue about how to program a good UI for the IPad. I've tried google, and I've read a little about UISplitViewController and PopoverController, but that's about it.

I haven't been able to find any good tutorial concerning interface design/programming on the IPad specifically. Does anyone here know about a good one?

The short version: Does anyone know of a good IPad UI programming tutorial for experienced IPhone programmers? (Preferrably something other than the Apple code examples.)

Comment: Clickable pictures, on a **touch** screen?

Comment: it's **tappable**, I edited :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to the user interface components that are unique to the iPad, and how to deal with them in your application, I highly recommend Daniel Steinberg and Eric Freeman's book "[iPad Programming: A Quick-Start Guide for iPhone Developers](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/sfipad/ipad-programming)".  They approach the subject as if you were familiar with iPhone development, but now want to get into the iPad.  I thought I understood the fundamentals well when I first picked up the book, but it taught me quite a bit more.

I taught a course on advanced iOS development recently, and one of the sessions was on the iPad and its unique UI components.  The videos and course notes for the [spring](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=407243032) and [fall](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=407243028) semesters can be found on iTunes U.  Look for the "iPad" class in the spring and "Views and view controllers" class in the fall.

When it comes to iPad interface design, that's something that people are still working out.  Designers are still experimenting with different ways of utilizing the larger touch surface, yet not cluttering things up.  Probably the best reference you'll find on this is the video for the [WWDC 2010](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) session 103: "iPad and iPhone User Interface Design".  I know that Josh Clark has also been giving presentations on his studies into iPad design, and notes from one of his recent talks can be found [here](http://lanyrd.com/2011/sxsw/scqtm/).

Comment: Thanks for an excellent answer! Have downloaded the linked resources, and gotten the ebook now, will check them out.

Answer (score 4):

Ray Wenderlich has some of the best iOS tutorials by far.

Check out these iPad tutorials he's done.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1040/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uisplitview-tutorial
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1063/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-custom-input-view-tutorial
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1111/how-to-port-an-iphone-application-to-the-ipad

Comment: Thanks zneak.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks! These seem to be exactly what I was looking for. Will check them out tomorrow!